# Game Designer or Game Programmer, please help me choose!

Tags: graphics, animation

I know this question is asked a lot but I am still so confused and overwhelmed by the different opinion and comments everybody has on the internet, that I wanted to ask my questions in a single thread and get the answered by you. I would really appreciate it if you could spend a couple of minutes reading this as I don't have anybody near me to talk to about this.

I'm about to finish High School (I have one year left) and until last year what I wanted to do with my life was pursue a degree in fields such as Accounting/Finance or Medicine since those are the "most competitive" ones and where most of the $$ are made. I was all about the money and recently I finally understood the importance of studying and doing what I really care and dream about and that such competitive fields would wipe out people like me who are not really "dedicated". 
Anyways, as the title says, I'm into games, but I'm not that average type of guy who is interested in this just because he has played lots of games in his childhood and thinks that would do great at this.

The thing is that even though I want to immerse myself in the gaming industry, I still don't know what specific jobs consist of, mainly the Game Designer and the Game Programmer (this is the same as a Game Developer right?). To give you an idea of what I can do, I am great at math, photoshop, I'm creative, curious and following my "leader instincts" I want to just not be "the tool" of someone while working (while I do acknowledge that I will have a boss who will be above me, the company's owner for example), but I do not want to be the person who will be with a group of other people who do the same thing. What I'm trying to say is that I want to come up with the idea of the game, sketch it, bring it to life and even decide what the world, characters and story will look like, but I don't want to just design the characters or the world of the game because someone else came up with it and now I'm just bringing to life their project. I don't want to be just the "drawer" or the Game's Art designer. I want to be independent and even give rules (yeah, I know, not right away most probably), but I want to be the one to give life to my own project.

On the other hand, I haven't tried programming but I do have solid math skills as I said and I don't want to just "toss" them. I haven't tried coding but from what I've been reading, some people say C++ is a nightmare. Is it really so "cut with knife" and already defined, that you can either go full artistic and be the visual dude, or the game designer, or go fully scientific and be the one to deal with the system of the game and be the programmer? Because as I said I really lean towards the designing part more, but I would like to code and not be totally ignorant on that part. I do want to code, but I would totally HATE to be the guy who deals with the numbers only. Yeah I want to do some of that, but designing, choosing the characters' sprites, costumes, gameplay, effects, storyline, etc. etc. seems much more interesting to me.

Another thing that bothers me the most is what I will study in University? I wont study in the US, although it's a dream of mine, but I can't afford it as an international student, so it would be a bit different for you who are from there and try to answer this, but I've seen most people recommend Computer Science, who say that a programmer can always become a designer in the future, but a designer can't do the programming part if he doesn't have any knowledge in that area. I've already read and "studied" the mythology, am educated in literature am thinking of taking psychology classes in my last High School year, but really, what do you suggest? I've seen universities offer classes for Digital Media or even Game Designing, but from what I've read this is a pretty new field and it wont help if I choose this major in university? 
Should I really go for a Computer Science degree? To make it clear to you, I HATE physics, I hope I wont be dealing with that. If I choose this route, how will I learn certain aspects of designing, such as animation, etc.?

I'm sorry for the huge text but I'm really confused and I feel like this is a really important part of my life, and being close to university I really need to make a decision fast, so that I can prepare myself as soon as I can.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Programmer.  You can apply that skill to design, coding and fields outside games, whereas design you can only apply to design.  In my opinion.

Comment: I'd say don't worry about what people say about programming languages at this point. Some people love C++ (me), some people hate it. **Just like any other thing anywhere** I say decide on this major before worrying about programming languages, or anything relatively deep, you might get the wrong impression. At least that's what I think...

Comment: Go with programming. You can extend to many other fields from there; programming doesn't kill opportunities, it just makes you look at the things around you from a different perspective. The best perspective, if you ask me.

Comment: @BogdanMarginean yeah I agree entirely, definitely the best perspective...

Comment: Best to choose programming or art, they have different pathways to different jobs, while design is just design.

Comment: There's no *correct* answer to this question, I'm voting to close. See the [FAQ] for some sites that would be better for discussion oriented questions like this one.

Comment: Also it's probably better to ask somewhere else, here at a *game development* Q&A site your going to get *game development* biased answers. So you should keep that in mind...

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure if there's anywhere appropriate to ask a question like this. The only person capable of providing the right answer is the OP.

Comment: Both! Because it's always cool to know more.

Comment: @user1306322 hmmm well said.

Answer (score 5):

**You need to be a programmer and an artist...**

...but lean heavily towards one side.

Game design is both of these things.

Programming is not hard. Programming is one of the easiest aspects of game development. Learning C++ is hard. Using C++ is the opposite of hard. The same goes for most programming languages.

A cabinet maker can design all the cabinets he wants, but unless he has knowledge of woodworking, the cabinets will never get built.

You don't need to be a good programmer. There are tons of development suites that take care of the heavy lifting. Take a look at [Unity](http://unity3d.com/). Unity is widely considered to be incredibly easy to use, but you still need to know how to program to use it.

It all depends on the tools you use. If you use Unity, you should be an "artist with knowledge of programming". If you create an engine in C++, you should be a "programmer with knowledge of art". It is senseless to limit yourself to one or the other.

**Find a friend.**

If you want to focus on the artistic side of things, find a programmer to help manifest your ideas. Similarly, if you decide to be a programmer, you should find an artist to create all of the visuals.

It is a bad idea to try to have equal skill of programming and art. Take a look at any indie game created by one person. If that person is a programmer, the game looks bad. If that person is an artist, the game is technically impaired. If the person is "both", the game is simply bad. (Although there is the occasional demigod who needs no help.)

Comment: +1 Interesting end section with the friend and one-man-indie-game.

Comment: I disagree with the last sentence. There **are** talented people out there.

Comment: I wish I could remember the name of *the* game that was made by a 2D artist in C# and XNA. He basically started learning to seriously code on that same project. It looked and felt badass - a 2D side-scrolling platformer for the X360.

Comment: @user1306322 That sentence wasn't meant as an assertion. I personally know many people who can create amazing games with no help. Many of these people participate in events such as Ludum Dare.

Comment: "Programming is not hard"... I wonder why I've spent the last 20 years of my life learning programming, and every day I feel more I won't ever be able to master everything there is to know about it.

Comment: It's not hard. There is just a pretty much unlimited amount of things to do and learn.

Comment: But.. that's the problem, I have no idea. I have never programmed, how do I know? I know I know, you'd be like "Don't ask us, start programming and then see how it works for you", but I don't know where to start, I'm just so overwhelmed. And I don't know if I'll learn what would be taught in schools.I tried learning HTML once but online I couldn't do much and I dropped it after a couple of days because it was very theoretical and I was dealing for the very first time with it. Do I need to start as a programmer or jump to the game design courses in university right away? Isn't it, too specific?

Comment: @JohnSimpson I'm afraid that your questions are simply too big for us to answer. I know that feeling of being overwhelmed and not knowing where to start, but we can't tell you how to start because it's different for everybody. It's just not a good question to ask on this site. Try asking on the http://www.gamedev.net/ forums. If you want to jump into programming, try http://www.learnpython.org/ or http://www.learncpp.com/ . This discussion is simply out of the scope of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JohnSimpson I suppose my point is that you shouldn't worry about it right now. You're not going to get away without learning how to program; the world will not let you. You will learn to program as the need arises. If you are serious about being a game developer, programming will be the least of your concerns.

Comment: I know that I'm the only one to determine what I will do, but that's not what I'm asking, I just want some sort of clarification of what's the difference between game designing and game programming, does the first deal with the design ONLY and the latter with coding ONLY or is the first a mix between coming up with the whole idea and manifesting it yourself? How should I not care for this right now, if not now, when, what should I choose to study in 1,5 years where I'll go to college? How can I get even a short term job after graduation that'll help me "survive" even if it's a short term one?

Comment: @JohnSimpson "Game Design" includes programming, but to varying extents. As the "game designer", you get to choose how much programming you will do. However, since you want an absolute answer, here it is: **A "Game Designer" designs the interaction between the systems of the game and the player; a "Game Programmer" implements these interactions into code.** What we've been trying to tell you, though, is that people in the industry don't really say "I am a game designer" or "I am a game programmer". We say **"I am a game developer, and my skills are programming / art / mechanics."**

Comment: So, the game designer just draws a "raw" model of the game, let's say the skeleton? Or does he deal with the graphics as well? Because I do want to design the graphics but I don't want them to be my only job, I want to design and code (mostly leaning towards designing) projects that most of the time are "born" in my brain. I'm sorry if it sounds abstract to you.
Also, really, I thought the game programmer, who deals with coding, is the same with the developer? Is the developer some sort of mix between the two, but leaning heavily towards one side?

Comment: @JohnSimpson **A)** the game designer will define how the art should look (i.e. style, time period, color themes, etc), but the actual creation of the art will (usually) be done by a dedicated artist. **B)** The term "game developer" usually refers to an individual or group that has the ability to produce a full game. It's somewhat rare for one company to design a game and send it off to another company to develop the game. Your typical game development studio will include a designer, programmer, and artist (these may be teams instead of individuals, and one person can have multiple titles).

Comment: @JohnSimpson I should probably mention that I am currently a member of a game development team, and nobody on the team has any kind of title. If something needs to be done, the person who has skills related to the task will go and get it done. This isn't specific to my company, either. Check out [how Valve does work](http://www.valvesoftware.com/company/Valve_Handbook_LowRes.pdf). Also, you seem like you really want to be the one making decisions. Does this mean you want to go indie, or do you want to work as part of a larger company?

Comment: But, if the game designer just defines how the art looks, isn't that pretty much, just coming up with the idea and doing nothing? I mean, it's like, saying that "this should look like this, and this like that", but the artist is the one who is actually doing the work. How come the game designer gets paid more if the artist is the one actually "bringing the project to life"?
So, you can't be a game developer, only a team can be called a game development team?

Comment: I really like the idea of going indie but I feel like (I could be totally wrong, not that I have any experience) that it turns more like a hobby than an actual job, I mean, at a company you would have a more stable and higher paying job, right?
Not that there's something wrong with working with larger companies, but to break it down, I just hate competition (in terms of ideas, being replaced by other people in the same company, etc.).
I've been reading more on this subject and I feel like you have freedom as an indie, but you have the $$ on larger companies, despite being "controlled".. :/

Comment: @JohnSimpson You are an endless fountain of questions. The game designer also designs the mechanics and interactions of the game. He makes the "blueprints" that the programmers and artists use as a guide. Designers get paid more because it's "their" game, the other guys are just doing work. In large companies, it could be a whole studio of artists that can create entire animated models in an afternoon. When it comes to indie devs compared to companies, indies usually start of as hobbyists, but become successful later on (or fail). Your last statement is correct.

Comment: I know, I know, I'm sorry..
If that's so, then this is even more confusing and not right for me..
My first intention was to draw, design and code, but mostly design, give shape to ideas but that falls to the game artist category and their salary is not that great based on what the internet says. I know I should stop whining, but I want to do the aforementioned stuff and be the one to make decisions, but I just can't risk to go indie and start this as a hobby, I want this to be a long term job, like, I would depend on this. Is it really so set in stone?

Comment: @JohnSimpson **1)** Never be sorry for anything. **2)** These job titles and descriptions are set in stone if you work for a large mega-company. However, there are a lot of small- and medium-sized publishers and developers that would love to have a team member who can design, make graphics, and program. Those salary numbers that you see on the net are kind if inaccurate. The term "game artist", in this case, refers to someone who *only* does art. Many game companies would love to have a designer who can also code and make art. Just because you make art doesn't mean you get less pay.

Comment: By "small sized publishers", do you mean just smaller companies that work the same as larger ones or hobbyists? Again I know I shouldn't be making decisions based on money but Im totally unfamiliar with this and just the thought of earning a living through video game programming sounds ridiculous in the country I come from. I come from a whole lot different environment and I'm actually more like trying to get to know the field better rather than just trying to decide what I want to do. So do you suggest I study Computer Science in university? I have no problem with it as long as it's relevant.

Comment: @JohnSimpson **1)** If you want better advice about the different types of publishers and jobs that are available, I highly suggest you ask on [Gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/). Situations vary depending on location, so the people on that site will be able to give you a more global view, and explain things much better than I have. **2)** Many schools offer a degree in "Game Design". I suggest you look around and see if any schools near you offer such a degree. Many schools in my area offer a "Computer Science" degree with a focus in "Game Design". It depends heavily on where you live.